# Errors when adding a wxStaticText with wxSmith

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

I am really new to c++ development(2 days) and everything has gone well so far, but when I add a wxStaticText through wxSmith, the auto-generated code won't compile:

error: 'StaticText1' was not declared in this scope

```
StaticText1 = new wxStaticText(this, ID_STATICTEXT1, _("Label"), wxPoint(8,8), wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT1"));
```

error: 'ID_STATICTEXT1' was not declared in this scope

```
const long dlgAbout::ID_STATICTEXT1 = wxNewId();
```

I also have a wxButton on the dialog, but does the exact same things and the compiler doesn't have those errors for the auto-generated button code:

```
btnClose = new wxButton(this, ID_BUTTON1, _("Close"), wxPoint(88,96), wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON1"));
```

and

```
const long dlgAbout::ID_BUTTON1 = wxNewId();
```

Full Source at http://pastebin.com/iyFF31eJ

Comment: Post entire cpp/h files in order to see what's really going on please. Like on pastebin.com

Comment: I downloaded the code you posted.  It compiled just fine for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code you pasted compiles for me, it must mean that the code you pasted is not the code that your compiler is attempting, and failing, to compile.  I think that you need to check that you may have a couple of versions of the dlgAbout.h file floating around and the compiler is using the wrong version, without the definition of ID_STATICTEXT1